# Why is my WIFI always on?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, battery, battery-history

I have turned off WIFI in the settings, but it's still always running. Doesn't this graph indicate that WIFI is really on all the time? How can this be when it's definitely "off" in Settings?

I'm worried that this constant WIFI use drains my battery and I want to avoid this.

This is a Nexus 4 running Kitkat 4.4.4.

I have also installed the [Llama automation app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&hl=en) which can optionally turn on WIFI every *x* minutes, but I have made sure that option is definitely turned off. This behavior continues even when Llama is not running. 
I don't think there's any other app on my phone that would have the capability to turn on WIFI on its own.

Is there some way I could find out whether one of the installed apps is responsible for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android is automatically keeping Wi-Fi on while the phone is sleeping (`Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep`) and always scans for available networks (`Scanning always available`). They must be keeping it on. Try disabling them from `Settings > Wi-Fi > Advanced`.

Comment: Yes, this setting was on "Always". I've switched it to "Only when plugged in" now. (If "Always" is the default value, then the chart doesn't really make any sense, does it?)

Comment: On the chart, the Wi-Fi should be always displayed as working when set as default, I don't know why "Always" is made the default value.

Comment: This setting should only matter if Wi-Fi is enabled, whereas OP seems to indicate that they've disabled it.

Comment: "Scanning always available" seems to be more of an issue, "Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep" should only matter if you have manually enabled the wifi, so it's ok imho

Answer (score 1):

WiFi always on is caused by you granting access googleto always being able to check for WiFi at any given time in googles point of view that means ALWAYS
You can disable it by going to your GPS settings and clicking the 3 dot menu > advanced unchecking the WiFi scanning hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Go to location. Select scanning options. Disable Wi-Fi and Bluetooth scanning. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Spotify or any media related control app seems to always be chatting over the network keeping it awake and active.

A Google Home assistant type device like Home Mini can cause the same issue, especially with the 'Let others control your cast media' option.